# How to set coordinates in image corners?

Tags: python, coordinates

So I have a picture with known coordinates for the four corners (lat, long) and I wish to plot some gps points on top of this.

The problem is: the image borders are not parallel to lat-long directions, so I can't use imshow's "extent" because then the corners need the same x or y.

My coordinates for the corners are (starting in bottom left corner, clockwise):

(57.786156, 14.096861)          (57.786164, 14.098304)
(57.784925, 14.096857)          (57.784928, 14.098310)

Can I rotate the image somehow to get lat-and long on the axis? Alternatively have a shifted coordinate system or something?

How would you do this?

imshow 'extent' and tried to transform the coordinates to [0 1] [0 1] system which seems difficult.